# sign in modal window submit button php

Tags: php, jquery

I have index.php inside in this has modal window with login link. Modal window is with username and password checking in mysql with php. But when I clicked submit button- no typing
username or password it's not showing php errors - 'You need to enter a username' or 'You need to enter a password'...When is refreshing index.php and I clicked login link it is showing ...
How I can resolve this problem on first click on submit button is cheking for mysql php error?

```
          <div id="basic-modal-content">
            <div id="winsign">

          <form action="" method="post" onSubmit="validate();"> 


           <?php

       include 'core/init.php';


       if (empty($_POST) === false) {
           $username = $_POST['username'];
           $password = $_POST['password'];

       if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[]= 'You need to enter a username and password';
               } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[]= 'We cant\'t find username. Have you registered?';
        } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[]= 'You haven\'t acticated your account!';  
            } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';      
            } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  
            header('Location: sign_in.php');
            exit();
            }
        } 
            print_r($errors);
    }
       ?>


            <span id="tpos">Username:</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="sbutton" id="modalbox" placeholder="Username">
            <br><br><span id="tpos">Password:</span>
            <br><input type="password" name="password" class="sbutton" id="modalbox" placeholder="Password">
            <br><br><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="cbutton"><span id="ttext">Remember me</span>
            <br><input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="signin" id="bsubmit">
            </input>
            </form>
```

That is in modal window and when i clicked submit button is not checking for php errors in first click and reload index.php When i clicked second time is there error but in first click is not showing errors and reload page index...

Comment: Well judging by your code, I'd say the problem is on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an onSubmit for your form.

Try something like this:

```
<form name="formname" action="index.php" method="post" onSubmit="validate();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should process the information first and check if it is empty using empty().

So something like this

```
    $error=0; $error_msg =''; 
    $username = $_POST['username'];  
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($_POST['submit'])
{
    if(empty($username)){ $error = 1; $error_msg .= //your error msg}
    if(empty($password)){ $error = 1; $error_msg .= //your error msg}
    if($error == 0){//do your login stuff}
}
```

Hope this helps